# Not able to make connection to a server process located on different network using in C

Tags: sockets, unix

I am trying to send messages between two system located on different network using C socket programming.
But when connect() system call initiated it is returning -1 so I am not able to connect to the server.
How can I get connect to a remote server located on different network or different machine. Same program is working when I am using client and server on local machine.

```
**Client code ----->**

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    int sockfd,portno,n;

    char buffer[256];


    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    if (argc<3)
        error("error port number not provided");

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd<0)
        error("error while creating socket ");

    server =(struct hostent *)gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(server == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }


    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);



    if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
        error("error while connecting..");
    while(strncpy(buffer,"bye",3)!=0){
        bzero(buffer,256);
        printf("\nYou:");
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

        //n= write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    n=send(sockfd,(char*)&buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
        if(n<0)


printf("message not delivered\n");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    //n= read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    n= recv(sockfd,buffer,255,0);
    printf("\nfrd:%s",buffer);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    }

**Server code -->**

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd,listenfd,portno,clilen,n;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    if (argc<2)
        error("error port number not provided");

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd<0)
        error("error while creating socket ");

    bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof serv_addr)<0)
        error("error while binding socket");
    listen(sockfd`enter code here`,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

            if ((listenfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clilen))<0)
            error("error while initializing listening");
    printf("listening for connections..");
while(strncmp(buffer,"bye",3)!=0){
        bzero(buffer,256);
//n= read(listenfd,buffer,255);
        n= recv(listenfd,buffer,255,0);
        if(n<0)
            error("no message");
        printf("\nfrd:%s",buffer);
        printf("\nyou:");
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
//n= write(listenfd,buffer,sizeof buffer);
        n=send(listenfd,(char*)&buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
        if(n<0)
            printf("message not sent");

    }
close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: could you supply the code you tried to use?

Comment: there's loads of client server examples out there in C, which use sockets; I'm sure you came across some of them. It's probably no working for you because of a small mistake somewhere, no way of telling without seeing what you tried.

Comment: Use `perror("connect")` instead of `error` : It shall give you a clue on the error.

Comment: Same program is working when I am using both client and server on local machine....

Comment: You've commented out the line where you tell the client what address to use for the server. It's always connecting to `0.0.0.0` because of the bzero, and that address works like `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of client code is the same as that in the server.

```
server =(struct hostent *)gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if(server == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

argv[1](http://hsembedded.blogspot.in) contains the name of a host on the Internet, e.g. [hsembedded.blogspot.in](http://hsembedded.blogspot.in) ;)
 The function:
     struct hostent *gethostbyname(char *name)
Takes such a name as an argument and returns a pointer to a hostent containing information about that host. The field char *h_addr contains the IP address. If this structure is NULL, the system could not locate a host with this name.
The mechanism by which this function works is complex, often involves querying large databases all around the country.

```
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
```

This code sets the fields in serv_addr. Much of it is the same as in the server. However, because the field server->h_addr is a character string, we use the function:
void bcopy(char *s1, char *s2, int length)
which copies length bytes from s1 to s2.

the error is actually due to absence of `#include<netdb.h>` in client code.